# EF Core SQLite не работает метод Include()

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, entity-framework-core

При вызове `Users.Include(a => a.Accounts).ToList();`
генерирует исключение

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid."

При работе с MySql все работает отлично

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такое поведение воспроизводится, если в классе `User` член `Account` является полем:

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<Account> Accounts;
}
```

Поменяйте его на свойство:

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<Account> Accounts {get; set;}
}
```